# Using JOINS, ORDER BY, and pivot tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

```
table: users
    id

table: tasks
    id

table: tasks_users
    user_id
    task_id
    is_owner
```

I have a `users` table, a `tasks` table and a pivot table `tasks_users`.

I would like to select all the users given a `task_id` and ordering by `tasks_users.is_owner`.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: `tasks_users` is called a junction table (or sometimes an association table).  It is *not* a pivot table.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this ...

```
 select u.users
    from users u 
         join tasks_users tu
         on u.id=tu.user_id 
         join tasks t
         on t.id=tu.task_id
    where t.task_id=your_id
  order by tu.is_owner
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simple

```
select u.id 
from users u
inner join tasks_users tu on u.id = tu.user_id 
inner join tasks t on t.id = tu.task_id
order by tu.is_owner;
```

Answer (score -2):

The following will perform a JOIN of tables "tasks" and "task_users", and return only users who have a task with the desired id:

```
SELECT users.id 
FROM tasks, task_users 
WHERE task_users.task_id = (desired id) 
ORDER BY tasks_users.is_owner
```

Comment: Why not use a join then?  Using old-style joins (multiple tables in the from and your join conditions in the where clause) is not considered to be good practice any longer.  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins